# Using IF/Then Statements with Option Buttons in UserForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to code the option buttons to give a value based off both being selected? I have tried multiple ways and seems I am getting nowhere. This is the last code I have tried and this is how I would like it to work if possible. The way this code is right now, I am only getting one value.

```
Private Sub OptBtn()

    Dim n As Long

    n = Sheets1.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert


    If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = True & Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = True Then
        Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"

    Else

        If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = True & Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = False Then
            Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "AVAILABLE"

        Else

            If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = False & Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = True Then
                Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = True And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = True`, `&` operator is for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `And` instead of `&`.

```
If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = True And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = True Then
    Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"
Else
    If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = True And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = False Then
        Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "AVAILABLE"
    Else
        If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value = False And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value = True Then
            Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

The code can be shortened like this:

```
If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value Then
    Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"
Else
    If Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Not Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value Then
        Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "AVAILABLE"
    Else
        If Not Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value Then
            Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = "ACTIVE"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I personally like the `Switch()` variation:

> [Switch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/switch-function): Evaluates a list of expressions and returns a Variant value or an expression associated with the first expression in the list that is True

```
Sheets1.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = Switch( _
    Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value, "ACTIVE", _
    Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Not Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value, "AVAILABLE", _
    Not Me.OptBtn_AddCard.Value And Me.OptBtn_ManagedBy.Value, "ACTIVE")
```

Comment: That solved it. Thanks so much! I figured I was doing something wrong. I tried the switch variation and now I'm hooked. Thanks again for showing me something new.